# How to recognize mouse wheel in MAUI view for desktop application

Tags: macos, desktop-application, maui

How to get notified for mouse wheel interaction for MacCatalyst and windows at MAUI platform.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I wanted mousewheel events from the platform-independent GraphicsView control in MAUI. No such event exists. But I found that on Windows, GraphicsView uses PlatformTouchGraphicsView, and there you have the event PointerWheelChanged.

A bit contradictionary that the selling argument for MAUI was that it should be so easy to write platform-specific code, but information about the platform-specific classes in MAUI is almost impossible to find.

This code will display the mouse coordinates and scroll length when you move the scroll wheel inside the GraphicsView.

```
<ScrollView x:Name="myScrollView">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <GraphicsView x:Name="myCanvas" WidthRequest="220" HeightRequest="80" />
        <Label x:Name="myLabel" WidthRequest="220" HeightRequest="80"/>


public partial class MainPage3 : ContentPage
{
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();

    #if WINDOWS
        Microsoft.Maui.Platform.PlatformTouchGraphicsView x = (PlatformTouchGraphicsView)myCanvas.Handler.PlatformView;

        x.PointerWheelChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            int mouseWheelDelta = e.GetCurrentPoint(x).Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
            Windows.Foundation.Point p = e.GetCurrentPoint(x).Position;

            if (mouseWheelDelta != 0)
            {
                myLabel.Text = mouseWheelDelta.ToString() + " -- " + p.ToString();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        };
    #endif

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1: Scrolling.**

What do you want to do based on mouse wheel interaction? If you simply want to scroll, or know when scrolling has occurred, then you can rely on ScrollView, and other views that handle scrolling themselves. E.g. [ScrollView.Scrolled event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrollview.scrolled?view=xamarin-forms).

---

**Answer 2: General use of mouse scroll wheel.**

Input functionality for mouse or keyboard has not yet been implemented in MAUI. Nor has a specification been finalized.

[Here is one mouse proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3669).

You could add a comment to that proposal requesting that mouse wheel support be included.

However, this might not be in the first release of MAUI, as the current emphasis is on stabilizing the functionality that is needed on all platforms (including mobile), some of which don't have mice.

---

In case anyone is wondering "shouldn't this be specified in .net 6?" (And then MAUI would simply use it.)

There are interactions between what is happening on the display (views or windows) and how mouse/keyboard input should be handled - it makes sense to put that input in the same code base that is displaying to the screen - therefore MAUI is a good place for it.

Especially given that touch is part of MAUI.

---

Until then, the solution is to make a [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) on each platform, to refer to the platform's APIs that you need.

Surprisingly, I'm not finding one that anyone has done for mouse on Windows and Mac.

Other than "implicitly", since a mouse can be used similar to a touch device. And text can be typed on a keyboard. The point is that there is no API specific to functionality that only makes sense if you have a physical mouse (scroll wheel) or a physical keyboard (global keyboard hooks).

---

**TBD**  I'll look into this further.

Basic approach would be to look at what WinUI 3 uses as input APIs.

On Windows Desktop app, forward to those input APIs. Write an adapter on other platforms (Mac, Linux).

I'll see if Uno Platform or Avalonia have taken this approach.

Comment: I have implemented my own handler to detect mouse events for windows, same tried to mac, added tap gesture and pan gesture, is possible to get to detect left or right mouse clicked on pan gesture? and mouse wheel scrolling delta?